# Import to non-existent module error from Terraform

Tags: terraform

I have this module in my code and I am trying to import the existing APIM to state.

```
module apim {
  source               = "source"
  environment          = var.environment
  prefix               = local.project
  resource_group_name  = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  location             = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  subnet_id            = module.network.apim_subnet_id
  sku                  = local.APIM_sku
  virtual_network_type = local.APIM_virtual_network_type
  action_group_id      = azurerm_monitor_action_group.action_group["ag-${local.project}-${var.environment}"].id
  tags                 = local.tags
}
```

Import command:

```
terraform import 'module.apim.azurerm_api_management.apim_network_integrated' /subscriptions/subid/resourceGroups/rg/providers/Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/APIM
```

I get this error:

```
│ Error: Import to non-existent module
│
│ module.perfdash-mvp.module.apim is not defined in the configuration. Please add configuration for this module before importing into it.
```

When I plan the code it gives output to create the APIM.

Comment: your import command the the module output dont match. have a look in `terraform state list` to see all the resources and their full name